# Calling method with attribute value in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, properties, invoke, custom-attributes

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method,AllowMultiple=true)]
public class MethodId : Attribute
{
    private int mId;
    public MethodId(int mId)
    {
        this.mId = mId;
    }

    public int methodId
    {
        get { return this.mId; }
        set { this.mId = value; }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Methods
{
    [MethodId(1)]
    public void square()
    {        }

    [MethodId(2)]
    public void Notify()
    {        }
}
```

---

How to access square() in main() or in any other class with the help of MethodId?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(int id)
{
        return typeof(Methods).GetMethods().
            Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<MethodId>().Count() > 0)
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<MethodId>().First().methodId == id)
            .First();
}
```

And usage:

```
var methodInfo = GetMethodInfo(1);
methodInfo.Invoke(new Methods(), null);
```

## NOTE:

This solution is only meant to display how to do it. **Not omptimised for performance.** Ideally you would **cache** the methodInfos.

Comment: Please explain :  methodInfo.Invoke(new Methods(), null);

Comment: The method is not static so you need an instance to run it, hence `new Methods()`. The other one is the parameters which it has none hence `null`.

Comment: Ok...But "new Methods()" is an instance created to call which method? It is just a new object.I am not able to catch this. What are we passing exactly? :)

Comment: You need to read the reflection stuff. I cannot explain it here in comments. Read about `MethodInfo`.